# How to remove stateless entity Java persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, stateless

I have the following situation with Java persistence:

```
public ReturnCodes startWork() {

    sessionBackup = (BaseService<Backup>) ctx.lookup("XYZ/BackupServiceImpl/local");

    Backup backup = new Backup();
    backup.setStatus(BackupStatus.EXECUTING);
    ....
    sessionBackup.save(Backup) //at this point is not actualy saved into DB

    ....//try to connect somewhere
    if ( !ConnectSuccess) {
        sessionBackup.remove(backup);
        return ReturnCodes.REQUESTABORT
    }
    ....
}

@Stateless
public class BackupServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<Backup> implements
    BaseService<Backup>
{

    @Override
    protected Class<Backup> getEntityClass()
    {
        return Backup.class;
    }
}
```

And the `save` and `remove` methods of `BaseServiceImpl`:

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<T extends Serializable> implements
    BaseService<T>
{

  protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public T save(T entity)
  {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.persist(entity);

    return entity;
  }

  public void remove(T entity)
  {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try
    {
      final Method method = getEntityClass().getMethod("getId");
      final String id = (String) ((T) method.invoke(entity));
      entity = em.find(getEntityClass(), id);
      em.remove(entity);
    }
    catch (final Exception ex)
    {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unexpected error", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to save into the DB in case `ConnectSuccess` fails, but the `remove` method fails to find the entity (because is not yet into the DB), and after returning `ReturnCodes.REQUESTABORT` the entity is saved.
How can I cancel the save?

Comment: Are you looking for database transaction and rollback? This one? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in this case you do a setRollbackOnly().

You may also throw an exception which will trigger the rollbackonly.

See http://www.developerscrappad.com/547/java/java-ee/ejb3-x-jpa-when-to-use-rollback-and-setrollbackonly/

By the way doing this in your code:

```
catch (final Exception ex)
{
  logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unexpected error", ex);
}
```

is too broad and will block rollback functionality.

Comment: So, after reading a little, what I want is to commit a CMT in the middle of the method, not at it's end. It this possible ? How ?

Comment: @Alex yes it's possible. You want to call YouDao.getEntityManager().flush(); http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush()

Comment: It's not working with flush, practically it blocks the table database (I check within SQL manager, at the query is running) until the method ends.. :(

Comment: @Alex Why do you need to commit in the middle of your method in the first place?

Comment: Because if you look at my pseudocode my method init a server backup, and after it marks the backup with EXECUTING status I need to save this to database and then continue with the backup job and after the backup job finish, it updates the backup info in the DB

Comment: I understand that you don't want the backup job to be part of the same transaction. So you should split your method and have seperate transactions. You have to manage transactions. As you use jpa & spring, you need @transaction annotations on your methods.

Comment: Solved ! Adding the following annotation forced to commit the transaction: @TransactionAttribute(value= TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)